# PHP reCaptcha not displaying on site

Tags: php, html, forms, recaptcha

I'm trying to get reCaptcha working for my form. The form itself works flawlessly without reCaptcha. Below is the relevant code from my .html and .php files.

The problem is that the reCAPTCHA widget isn't showing up on the page at all. I can get the submit button working but of course it always fails because of the missing widget.

sign_up.html

```
<div id="form">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var RecaptchaOptions = {
        theme : 'white'
    };
    </script>
    <form class="pure-form" action="myprocessingscript.php" method="post">        
        <fieldset class="pure-group">
            <input name="field1" type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Name">
            <input name="field2" type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Username">
            <input name="field3" type="email" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Email">
        </fieldset>
        <?php
            require_once('recaptchalib.php');
            $publickey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(censored)"; 
            echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?>
        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary">Skicka</button>      
    </form>
</div>
```

myprocessingscript.php

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(censored)";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2']) && isset($_POST['field3'])) {
    $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . '-' . $_POST['field3'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('submissions.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
  }

?>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what is the html output?

Comment: "The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.(reCAPTCHA said: incorrect-captcha-sol)" Is that what you mean? I mean it forwards to the php correctly when clicking submit but the widget isn't showing up on the site.

Comment: Try this: echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error); What is the error?

Comment: I put it in the php part of sign_up.html and nothing seems to have changed. No new error message, still forwards to the php where it gives the reCAPTCHA error.

Comment: Did you print $error?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/fXMoOYj.png - Two prints for redundancy but nothing is showing up on the site (key edited obv.).

Comment: show us the html output of recaptcha_get_html($publickey);

Comment: How exactly do I do that? My only experience with html is an intro class and self learning.

Answer (score 0):

1.Save you `sign_up.html` page as `sign_up.php`
and remove the code as first make it work without customization. 
2.Have you uploaded `recaptchalib.php`file to your root directory.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            var RecaptchaOptions = {
            theme : 'white'
        };
        </script>
```